# Proof of non diagonalizibility of higher matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization

So the proof is to show that if a regular matrix A is not diagonalizable in $ M_n(\Bbb C) $ then no power of $A^k$ for $k \in \Bbb N$ so i started it with a proof by contradiction suppose $A^k$ is diagonalizable then there exists a minimal polynomial such that $p(A^k)=0$ so if we write that polynomial as $p=(x-a_1)...(x-a_n)$ but then i got stumped on how taking $k$-th roots will lead to a solution so when i checked the answer it said take the $k$-th root of all the $a_i$'s and we get a new polynomial $q=(x-a_{11})(x-a_{12})....(x-a_{1k}).....(x-a_{nk})$ where $a_{11},..,a_{1k}$ are roots of the original and for this polynomial $q(A)=0$ i got to this myself but i dismissed the correct way to a proof .

1. Why can we factorize $p$ to $q$ like so cause if i multiply it i dont see how it turns back to p?
2. what will guarantee that $A$ will be its root? i dont get how we cant have a remainder when we multiply everyting eg i know we will get $x^k -a_1$ cause i think ($a_{11}*...*a_{1k}=a_1$) but what will happen to the rest of it?

please give me a detailed explanation or at least a link to where i can read in detail on factorin or such things i have a knowledge gap in

edit: i forgot to state matrix A is regular fixed it

Comment: Are you missing a part of the initial statement? i.e "...Then no power of $A^K$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}...$" does what?

Comment: I believe OP means that if $A$ is not diagonalizable, then neither is $A^k$ for any integer $k \geq 2.$

Comment: sorry i worded it badly  @Carlo is right. thats what i meant

Comment: The statement is not true. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ is not diagonalisable but $A^2=0$ is diagonalisable. You need to impose an additional requirement that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @user1551 you are right the problem stated A is a regular matrix, but since i was so preoccupied with the rest of the problem i forgot to state it. im sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, we will assume that $A^k$ is diagonalizable for some integer $k \geq 2.$ We have therefore that the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $A^k$ can be written as a product of distinct linear factors, i.e., $p(x) = (x - c_1) \cdots (x - c_n)$ with $c_i \neq c_j$ for all pairs of integers $i \neq j.$ Using the fact that $p(A^k) = 0$ gives that $0 = p(A^k) = (A^k - c_1 I) \cdots (A^k - c_n I)$ so that $A$ satisfies the polynomial $q(x) = (x^k - c_1) \cdots (x^k - c_n).$ Considering that the underlying field is $\mathbb C,$ each of the factors $x^k - c_i$ [splits into distinct linear factors](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf), hence the polynomial $q(x)$ splits into distinct linear factors. But the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $q(x),$ hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits into distinct linear factors, i.e., $A$ is diagonalizable --- a contradiction. QED.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix that is not diagonalizable, then the genuine eigenvectors of $A$ do not span the space. If we look at eigenvectors of $A$ they take the following form:

$$Av_i=\lambda_jv_i$$
For some $i,j\in{1,2,...,m}$ where $m\leq n$. Let's prove that $A^k$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$ with eigenvalues equal to $\lambda_j^k$ for $k\geq 2$ by induction. Base case:
$$A^2v_i=\lambda_j^2v_i$$
Now assuming the $kth$ case prove the $k+1th$ case. So we have:
$$A^kv_i=\lambda_j^kv_i$$
Applying A from the left to both sides:
$$A^{k+1}v_i=\lambda_j^{k+1}v_i$$
Thus we have shown that $A^k$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$. However, if $A^k$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$ that means that the eigenvectors of $A^k$ do not span the space, and thus $A^k$ is not diagnolizable.

Comment: Correction: what you have shown is that every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A^k.$ One does not even need induction for this: given that $Av = \lambda v,$ we have that $$A^k v = A^{k - 1}(Av) = A^{k - 1} (\lambda v) = \lambda A^{k - 1} v = \lambda A^{k - 2} (Av) = \lambda A^{k - 2} (\lambda v) = \lambda^2 A^{k - 2} v = \cdots = \lambda^k v.$$ Given that $A^k v = \mu v,$ why is it true that $Av = \lambda v?$

Comment: The JCF shows that there isn't a case where $A^k$ has eigenvalues other than $\lambda_j^k$

Comment: I agree with that, but I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: Perhaps I don't completely understand the point of the question, what are you pointing out?

Comment: Ostensibly, you have only proven that every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A^k,$ but your claim is that $A$ and $A^k$ have *the same* eigenvectors. Put another way, your proof (in my opinion) only concludes $$\{v \,|\, Av = \lambda v \} \subseteq \{v \,|\, A^k v = \mu v \};$$ however, the reverse inclusion remains to be seen.

Comment: We know that $A^K$ only has eigenvalues of $\lambda^k$ we also know all the eigenvectors $A$ are eigenvectors of $A^K$ with eigenvalues $\lambda^k$, how does that not imply that $A$ and $A^k$ have the same eigenvectors

Comment: For instance, if $A$ is nilpotent, then we have that $A^k = 0$ for some integer $k \gg 0.$ But in this case, every nonzero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^k$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0,$ i.e., we have that $A^k v = 0 = 0v$ for every vector $v.$ Consider the matrix $A = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr).$ Observe that $A^2 = 0,$ but the only eigenvector of $A$ is $(1, 0)^T.$ Of course, OP assumes that $A$ is invertible, so we can rule out my example, but your argument in general does not hold.

Comment: It holds if A is invertible though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110468/discussion-between-carlo-and-christopher-quinn-la-fond-jr).